# How to perform multiple drag gestures using XCUICoordinate in XCTest without releasing the element in-between?

Tags: swift, xctest, xcuitest

In my app, there's a card view, and when it's dragged to a corner of the screen (Left, Right, Up, Down), the screen displays the corner to which the card is dragged. I've written a UI test to validate this behavior, but it currently requires me to create four separate cards to run the test. This is because the card is released after the following call:

```
cardCenterCoordinate.press(forDuration: 0.1, thenDragTo: cardCenterCoordinate.withOffset(offset))
```

Is there a way to keep the drag gesture active throughout the entire process and move the same card to the four different directions, then return it to the center without releasing it?

```
func testDragInteractionOnPracticeScreenFlashcards() throws {
    let cardView = app.staticTexts["Card"]
    XCTAssertTrue(cardView.waitForExistence(timeout: 5))

    let hittableTimeout = 3.0

    let cardCenterCoordinate = cardView.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.5))
    let screenSize = app.windows.element(boundBy: 0).frame.size

    let distanceToMoveInX = screenSize.height * 0.5
    let distanceToMoveInY = screenSize.width * 0.5

    let checkpoints: [(String, CGVector)] = [
        ("Right", CGVector(dx: distanceToMoveInX, dy: 0)),
        ("Top", CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -distanceToMoveInY)),
        ("Left", CGVector(dx: -distanceToMoveInX, dy: 0)),
        ("Down", CGVector(dx: 0, dy: distanceToMoveInY))
    ]

    for (label, offset) in checkpoints {
        cardCenterCoordinate.press(forDuration: 0.1, thenDragTo: cardCenterCoordinate.withOffset(offset))
        XCTAssertTrue(app.staticTexts[label].waitForExistence(timeout: hittableTimeout))
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if you could chain the drag&drop, all XCUITest actions are synchronous on the main thread which means you cannot have a drag action and do some kind of assertion at the same time - you need to drag, assert, drag, assert, drag, assert and so on